# Nonogram with story

Tags: logical-deduction, story, grid-deduction, nonogram

Fellow puzzlers, here's a nonogram I made for you. But it also has a story!

> Two bored male casino dealers are waiting at the craps table. A very attractive blond woman arrives and bets $20,000 on a single roll of the dice. She says:
> "I hope you don't mind, but I feel much luckier when I'm completely nude."
> With that, she strips down, rolls the dice, and yells, "Come on, baby, Mama needs new clothes!" As the dice come to a *[Solution]*

[image]

Comment: Puzzles with stories that objectify women are better off without the story.

Comment: @GregMartin Don't see any objectification here unless you add it there yourself. This reads more like an anecdote (joke story) to me. And the solution corroborates that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solved nonogram:

> [image]

The clear squares finish the story.
*As the dice come to a*

> stop she jumps up and down and squeals: "YES! YES! I WON, I WON!" She hugs each of the dealers, picks up her winnings and her clothes, and quickly departs. The dealers stare at each other dumbfounded. Finally, one of them asks: "What did she roll?" The other answers: "I don't know, I thought you were watching."